# Find conjugate function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, conjectures

> $A\in R^{m\times n},\ rankA = m,\ f(y) -\text{ Convex function,} \ f:R^m\rightarrow R.$ Let $g(x) = f(Ax)$
> Find $g^*(y)$.

Because$x\rightarrow Ax$ - Affine transformation $\implies g(x)$ - is convex as well.

Because $rank{A}=m \implies g:R^m \rightarrow R$.

Because $g(x)$ is convex upwards $-g(x)$ is convex downwards and has $sup$ (only one).

Let's notice that $<x,y> - g(x)$ is also convex downwards.
$$k(x,y)=<x,y>-g(x)$$
$$k_x'(x,y)=\bar{y}-\nabla g(x)=\bar{y}- A^T\nabla f(Ax)=0$$
$$\nabla f(Ax) = (A^T)^{-1}y$$
$$g^*(y) = \sup_{R^m}{k(x,y)}=<x,y>-...$$

How can I precede starting from this moment?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $n = m$, so that the inverse of $A^T$ exists, you can continue your derivation as
$$
g^*(y) = \sup_{x} \left\{
\langle x, y \rangle - f(Ax)
\right\} =
\sup_{x} \left\{
\langle Ax, (A^T)^{-1} y \rangle - f(Ax)
\right\} \\
= \sup_{z} \left\{
\langle z, (A^T)^{-1} y\rangle - f(z)
\right\} = f^*((A^T)^{-1} y).
$$

The key steps above are:

- Noting that $\langle x, y \rangle = \mathsf{tr}(x^T y) = \mathsf{tr}(x^T A^T (A^T)^{-1} y) = \langle Ax, (A^{T})^{-1} y\rangle$ (second equality).
- Since $A$ is full-rank, every $z \in \mathbb{R}^m$ can be written as $Ax$ for an appropriate $x$ (third equality).